# How to align image to left in angular material mat-card?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to aling image to left side in Angular material with mat-card component, however my image still have some margin (left, up, down). I assume it's because I've used mat-grid.
So what should I do to solve this.

This is what I have:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-a3gaj2

And this is what I expect:
[image: al]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<mat-card class="home-card">
    <mat-card-content class="home-card-content">
      <img mat-card-image
        src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg"
        alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
      <div>
        <div>Second</div>
        <div>Third</div>
        <div>Fourth</div>
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
}


body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}


.home-card {
    border-radius: 4px;
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 1000px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 0;

    .mat-card-image {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .home-card-content {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;

      & > * {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex: auto;
        max-width: 50%;

        &:first-child {
          border-top-left-radius: 4px;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        }

        &:last-child {
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: start;
          padding: 8px;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect, but corners in image are not rounded. Mat-card has rounded corners.

Comment: <mat-card> border radius:
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/card/card.scss#L8

I updated my answer.

Comment: Great. One more question. If I would have more divs on the right side, eg.  `<div>Second</div> <div>Third</div>  <div>Fourth</div>`. How can I put it one below the other and align to left? Because now all div's are in the same line.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to apply only this css to set image, this css set all image same size no matter it is small or big.

```
object-fit: cover;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

Comment: This css apply on img tag.

Answer (score 0):

In [example](https://material.angular.io/components/card/examples) on `<img>` setted `margin: 0 -16px 16px -16px;` via `.mat-card-image`
But negative margin is bad practice

Just add you own css selector on `<mat-card>` with `padding: 0`

Comment: Exactly, your solution is not a good practice. I think it can be done better.